# Angular get data from kerberos authentication

Tags: angular, kerberos, angular-route-guards

I have an angular application with a backend. The authentication is managed by the browser with Kerberos before the app has started. The response contains a JWT with roles in it.

My approach is an extra HTTP call to the server when the app is starting to get the users credentials. This is realized with the `APP_INITIALIZER` in `app.module.ts`, so I already have the credentials when the app has started.

```
providers: [
    ...,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: Utilitys.authServiceFactory,
      deps: [AuthenticationService],
      multi: true   
    }]
```

This is working fine. **But my question is:** Do I have to make an extra call or is there a way to get the response from the browsers request?

**If yes:** How is it possible?

**If no:** Is the `APP_INITIALIZER` a recommended way to fetch the data only once? Or should I protect all routes with a `route guard` that does the HTTP call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get data only once your application has started, you could do this also with `Route Guards`.

You could define a componentless route that is protected by a route guard like this:

```
// Route Guard
canActivate(): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.yourService.isAuthenticated()) {
      return true;
    }
    return this.loginService.login();
}

// Routes
{
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'comp1', component: Comp1 },
      { path: 'comp2', component: Comp2 },
      ...
    ]
}
```

This way every route is protected by your guard and you can check if your user is logged in / authenticated to access your application.

Note that your regular components would be children of the componentless protected route.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I haven't found a solution to get the users information without an extra http call to the server.

The `APP_INITIALIZR` worked fine for my initial use-case. But later my `AuthenticationService` were expanding and the `APP_INITIALIZR` can't handle Services that need to inject the router due to cyclic dependency. Therefore I recommend the solution in the accepted answer.